# How to join users from subscribers to actual signup

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

How would you do a join if you had users that have subscribed and want to see how many of them actually have accounts. This link is done via email

Edit-

More details..

The subscribers table has the id, the email address and the datetime fields.

The users table has its own ids, the email address, the username as well as other fields to do with the user.

Comment: More details would help, what is the table structure?

Comment: @IanSellar I edited the post with more details

Comment: @ShemsEddine so if they have a e-mail address then this means they have an account? What do you mean by 'This link is done via email'

Comment: @SEBBINFIELD I mean I want to find all the users that have put their emails in the subscription list in, the users table which has the users that have actually signup when I emailed them. The easiest way I can think of is to go through all of the subscribers and compare them the every single user until there is a match but in that case, I will be wasting a lot of processing power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a left join to join the tables. Have the e-mail address column in the select statement which you want to see if they are NULL or not.

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (users), with the matching rows in the right table (subscribers).

So in the answer to your question, the null values in the e-mail address field is what you want to see if users in the subscribers table do not have an e-mail.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN subscribers
ON users.column_name=subscribers.column_name;
```

This is my understanding of what you want from your description.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT <your columns> FROM users
WHERE EXISTS (select email from subscribers where subscribers.email = users.email)
```